# Align last two flexbox justify-content item to the left

Tags: css, flexbox

How is it possible to align the last two items to the left?
Sometimes there is a huge gap between the last two items. Is there some flexbox directive that fixes that?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
  <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
  <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
  <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
  <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
  <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
  <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
  <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying to find a solution from recommended. Looks like i need to change it and will post here when ready.

Comment: OK. its not really a duplicate. This is my solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZjWmQ